# JAVA SERVER SOCKET - Help it won't send

Tags: java, sockets, client, server

I've been working on this for almost a week, I've stripped it down to the bare basic code and the client would still not receive message from the client. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Server {

    Socket socket;
    JTextArea textShow;
    PrintWriter writer;
    static String message;

    JButton buttonSend;

    // LAUNCH
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server servobj = new Server();
        servobj.Server();

    }

    public void Server() throws Exception {

        // dECLARE
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("The Server");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        textShow = new JTextArea(10, 40);
        JTextField textSend = new JTextField(35);
        buttonSend = new JButton("SEND");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textShow,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        // INITIALIZE
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.add(textShow);
        textShow.setLineWrap(true);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        panel.add(textSend);
        panel.add(buttonSend);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        setupServer();

    }

    // SETTING UP THE SERVERS
    public void setupServer() throws Exception {

        ServerSocket servSock = new ServerSocket(443);

        socket = servSock.accept();
        System.out.println("Server Socket accepted");

        writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        writer.println("Hello");
        System.out.println("MESSAGE SENT");

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        message = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(message);

    }

}
```

```
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Client {

    Socket socket;
    PrintWriter writer;
    static JTextArea textShow;
    TextField textSend;

    // LAUNCH
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Client clientobj = new Client();
        clientobj.Client();

    }

    public void Client() throws Exception {

        // dECLARE
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Client");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        textShow = new JTextArea(10, 40);
        JTextField textSend = new JTextField(35);
        JButton buttonSend = new JButton("SEND");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textShow,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        // INITIALIZE
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.add(textShow);
        textShow.setLineWrap(true);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        panel.add(textSend);
        panel.add(buttonSend);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        setupConnections();
    }

    // SETTING UP THE CONNECTION
    public void setupConnections() throws Exception {

        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 443);
        System.out.println("Client accepted");

        // SETUP RECIEVE MESSAGE
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        System.out.println("Done sam");
        String Message = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(Message);
        System.out.println("Sent");

        // SETUP SEND MESSAGE
        writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        writer.println("Hello G");
        writer.flush();
        System.out.println("Network Established");

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: We do not need several yards of irrelevant GUI code to debug a networking problem. Please reduce your code to a small example  that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you knew what could be the problem, but you didn't correct it everywhere.

In your client you have

```
// SETUP SEND MESSAGE
writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
writer.println("Hello G");
writer.flush();
```

So you realize that `PrintWriter` will not send your message immediately, but will place it in inner buffer, so to enforce sending you ware invoking `flush`.

But in server you are not flushing that message

```
writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
writer.println("Hello");
System.out.println("MESSAGE SENT");
```

Simplest way to avoid such problems is using PrintWriter which will flush automatically, like when you are using `println`. Such writer can be created by [`PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.OutputStream-boolean-) constructor

where we can read that

> `autoFlush` - A boolean; if true, the `println`, `printf`, or `format` methods will flush the output buffer

So consider using this constructor in both classes

```
writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
```

and when you send message via `println` it should be flushed automatically.

---

There are also few other possible problems in your current code

- you are creating local socket variables instead of initializing socket fields
- you have methods with same name as constructors which is not good practice, so instead of

  ```
  public void Client(){

  }

  Client client = new Client();
  client.Client();//<-here you are calling your method
  ```

  You should remove return type `void` to make that method constructor so your code will be reduced only to

  ```
  Client client = new Client();
  ```

Comment: Thank you Pshemo, I'm going to implement those methods to the code, I will tell you if it works :)

Comment: Thank you Pshemo, it works!, I'm fairly new to JAVA. :)